# How to indent text without adding whitespace in a sublime-package?

Tags: sublimetext3, word-wrap, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to add syntax highlighting for jinja2.
Specifically what I'm after is **indenting statement blocks** like {% if %} and {% for %}.

[How jinja2 looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH7BR.png)  [What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDEYx.png)

However, **I don't want to just add whitespace**, as this will show up in the template file.

I know that there is a way to add indentation without whitespace before it, because it happens in the Python syntax when Word-Wrap is enabled:

[Long line broken by Word Wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjCGh.png)

I assume this can be achieved by creating/modifying sublime packages, but since I'm new to those I'd love some guidance. There also might be another possible way of achieving that, which I'm not aware of.

Thanks!

EDIT:

After more searching in ST prefrences I've found "indent_subsequent_lines", which seems to be responsible for the non-whitespace indent in Python Syntax. So this might not work as a solution.

I'm keeping this question open in case someone does has the answer, but after finding "indent_subsequent_lines" I'm less convinced that there is simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, there is no way to do this with a plugin in Sublime. Indentation following word wrap is controlled by Sublime's internals, and is not accessible via the Python API. This makes sense, because you would presumably not want one text editor magically changing the presentation of your code by indenting it, while another editor displays it all left-aligned. If you want your Jinja markup indented, you'll have to take the hit and modify your template(s).